# General questions on measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{A}$ a sigma-algebra on $X$. Two measures are said to belong to the same class iff. they have the same null sets. 
Together with every measurable map between measure spaces $\phi : (X, \mathcal{A}, \mu) \to (Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ comes an induced measure on $Y$, $\mu_\phi(B) := \mu(\phi^{-1}(B))$. $\phi$ is called measure class preserving (with respect to the fixed measures $\mu, \nu$) iff. $\nu$ and $\mu_\phi$ are in the same class.

One can define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{A}$: For $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$, we put
$$A \sim B ~\text{iff.}~ (A \setminus B \cup B \setminus A) ~\text{is a null set}$$

if $\phi$ is measure class preserving, $\phi$ induces a sort-of dual map

$$\phi^* : \mathcal{B}/\sim ~ \to ~ \mathcal{A}/\sim, ~~~~~~ \phi^*([B]) := \phi^{-1}(B)$$

One can put a topology on $\mathcal{A}/\sim$ by using the bijective map

$$\iota : \mathcal{A}/\sim ~ \to Z \subset L^\infty(X), \iota([A]) := \chi_A$$

with $Z = \{ f \in L^\infty : f^2 = f ~~\text{almost everywhere}\}$ and then taking the pullback topology of the isomorphism $\eta : L^\infty \to (L^1)^*, \eta(f)(g) = \int_X f(x)g(x) d\mu(x)$ where we take the weak * topology on $(L^1)^*$.

In the book I am reading currently (Zimmer, Erodic theory and semisimple groups, p. 151) there are some statements about these things and I am unable to verify a single one of them. Can someone help?

1) $Z$ is closed in $L^\infty$

2) if $\phi$ is measure class preserving, then $\phi^*$ is a homeomorphism onto its image

3) the topology on $\mathcal{A}$ does not depend on the measure class of $X$

Comment: I have a question w.r.t. 2). Do you mean that $\phi$ is measure class preserving if $\mu_\phi\sim \nu$ for some fixed $\mu$ and $\nu$? Then $\phi^*$ does not have to be injective: fix some points $\hat x\in X$ and $\hat y\in Y$, and define: $\mu = \delta_{\hat x}$, $\nu = \delta_{\hat y}$ and $\phi(x) \equiv \hat y$. Then $\mu_\phi = \nu$ but
$$
  \phi^*(B) = \begin{cases}
X,&\text{ if }\hat y\in B,
\\
\emptyset,&\text{ if }\hat y\notin B
\end{cases}
$$
and is not necessarily one-to one.

Comment: @Ilya: I forgot something and edited. Thanks for pointing that out!!

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. Any ideas why $Z$ is closed?

Comment: As i said, i have no clue... maybe $f \mapsto f^2$ is continuous on $L^\infty$ or if one takes a limit of $\{0,1\}$ functions in the above sense, then assuming the contrary, the set of $x$ such that the limit function does not take values in $\{0,1\}$ is of measure $> 0$. Then one has to figure out a nice $L^1$ function to integrate against...